# xamarin.iOS 13.14 pkg installer - Visual Studio xamarin.iOS downgrade

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

Ok,

Maybe its just been a long day, but I cannot find Xamarin.iOS d16.4 13.14.0.21 pkg download for the life of me.

Backstory:

I ran into some Xamarion.iOS compatibility issues and ended up having to downgrade xamarin.iOS sdk from 13.16 to 13.10. The link to the different xamarin.iOS pkg's can be [found here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios).

Sidestory:

Once downlaoded just double click the file and this will open up the installer. Restart Visual Studio and check the xamarin.iOS version by going to Visual Studio > About visual Studio > Show Details.

Issue:

I am still facing issues due to my physical device being on iOS 13.3.1, which is not supported by xamarin.iOS 13.10. So, I need to upgrade, not to 13.16, but to 13.14 which has support for iOS 13.3.1. Where can I find a downloadable pkg with an installer for 13.14? Can someone drop a link to where I can download the pkg.

I am on a Mac machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

From [the shared link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios) can find the previous version of Xamarin iOS , click **relesases** as follow:

[image]

Then you will see the previous version of Xamarin iOS :

[image]

========================update================================

If want to get packages from previous version , you can click here :

[image]

The redirect **page** will show the pkg link as follow :

[image]

Comment: How can I simply get to the installer within the zip file? I want to make this as easy as it was to download the version in the link that I provided.

Comment: @JClark Okey , that link also can get packages . I have updated anaswer , you can have a look when you have time .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT once i downloaded the pkg file do i have anything to do ? ( a place to put it or idk)

Comment: @codetime Hi ,then the `pkg` file can be installed on Mac. After installed completely, the vs for mac will work for the previous version.